# ADO stream failes to save BLOB loaded from database

Tags: c++, stream, ms-access-2007, blob, ado

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

I have written demo app in my attempt to learn how to use `ADO` streams. Everything works fine except in one special case. Let me start by giving relevant information:

I am using `WinAPI` to create GUI, and am loading( and saving it on the disk )/inserting BLOB on a button press. Buttons are in a dialog box.

### PROBLEM:

When I press button for inserting BLOB into database I can see it being inserted ( I keep MS Access open ). If I try to load any existing BLOB from database nothing occurs, but no errors are signaled.

However, if I perform insert, **then close and reopen dialog box**, pressing the button for loading BLOB and saving it into disk works well.

I work on Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013 on a x64 dual core CPU laptop ( this might be important to mention ). *I have tested my app on C:\ partition where OS is, just thought to mention in case it is relevant.*

**EDIT :**

*I have tried my app on D partition and it works. This means that the problem lies somewhere in the permissions. Can you help me with this because I have no clue how o start solving this?*

**END OF EDIT**

### SSCCE:

To help you even further, follow carefully instructions to create very minimal code example that reproduces the problem:

1.) Create `default Win32 project` in Visual Studio.

2.) In `stdafx.h` add following just below `#include <windows.h>` :

```
#include <comutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <string>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment( lib, "comsuppw.lib")
#pragma comment( lib, "shlwapi.lib")
```

3.) Add the following in your main `.cpp` file just below `#include` directives:

```
#import <C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\System\\ado\\msado15.dll>  \
    rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )
```

4.) add the following function above dialog box procedure `About` :

```
BOOL OpenFile(HWND hDlg, LPWSTR szFileName, LPWSTR szFilter)
{
    // prepare OPENFILE dialog 
    OPENFILENAME ofn;

    memset(&ofn, 0, sizeof(ofn));
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hDlg;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = szFilter;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFileName;
    ofn.lpstrFile[0] = L'\0';
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST |
        OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_HIDEREADONLY |
        OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = L".pdf";

    if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

5.) Replace `About` dialog procedure with this:

```
// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    // connection string
    static wchar_t bstrConnect[MAX_PATH];
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // create connection string by choosing database 
        wchar_t szFile[MAX_PATH];
        OpenFile(hDlg, szFile, L".accdb\0");
        swprintf_s(bstrConnect, MAX_PATH, 
            L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = %s;", szFile);
    }
         return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON1)  // save BLOB to database
        {
            wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"";

            if (OpenFile(hDlg, szFileName, L"All files\0*.*"))
            {
                try
                {
                    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

                    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn(L"ADODB.Connection");
                    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS(L"ADODB.Recordset");

                    hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, 
                        L"", L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

                    // create new recordset 
                    pRS->Open( L"test", _variant_t((IDispatch*)pConn, true),
                        ADODB::adOpenKeyset, 
                        ADODB::adLockOptimistic, 
                        ADODB::adCmdTable);

                    // create stream object
                    ADODB::_StreamPtr pStream(L"ADODB.Stream");
                    // set stream type
                    pStream->Type = ADODB::adTypeBinary;
                    // missing parameter for Open 
                    _variant_t varOptional(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);  
                    // open stream
                    pStream->Open(varOptional, 
                        ADODB::adModeUnknown, 
                        ADODB::adOpenStreamUnspecified,
                        _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""));

                    // open selected file
                    hr = pStream->LoadFromFile(szFileName);

                    // error checking
                    if (FAILED(hr))
                        throw _com_error(hr);

                    // add new blank  record
                    pRS->AddNew();
                    // position stream to beginning
                    pStream->Position = 0;
                    // insert data to recordset

                    PathStripPath(szFileName);  // leave only filename

                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"tip")->Value = szFileName;
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"field")->Value =
                        pStream->Read(ADODB::adReadAll);

                    // insert data
                    pRS->Update();

                    //cleanup
                    pRS->Close();
                    pConn->Close();
                    pStream->Close();
                    CoUninitialize();
                    MessageBeep(0);
                }
                catch (_com_error e)
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, (LPWSTR)e.Description(), L"", 0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_BUTTON3)  // load BLOB and save it into disk
        {
            try
            {
                // napravi upit

                HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

                ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn(L"ADODB.Connection");
                ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS(L"ADODB.Recordset");

                hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, L"", L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

                // create stream object
                ADODB::_StreamPtr pStream(L"ADODB.Stream");
                // set stream type
                pStream->Type = ADODB::adTypeBinary;
                // missing parameter for Open
                _variant_t varOptional(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR); 
                // open stream 
                pStream->Open(varOptional, 
                    ADODB::adModeUnknown, 
                    ADODB::adOpenStreamUnspecified,
                    _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""));

                // primary key is taken from edit control
                wchar_t query[200] = L"";
                swprintf_s(query, 200, L"select tip, field from test where ID = %d;",
                    (int)GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, FALSE, FALSE));

                pRS->Open(query, _variant_t((IDispatch *)pConn, true),
                    ADODB::adOpenUnspecified, ADODB::adLockPessimistic,
                    ADODB::adCmdText);

                if (NULL == pRS)
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"Empty recordset!", L"", 0);

                hr = pStream->Write(pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"field")->Value);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"stream write failed", L"", 0);

                // save to file
                // store this file on disk
                // int he same place our app is running
                wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"";

                swprintf_s(szFileName, MAX_PATH, L".\\%s",
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"tip")->Value.bstrVal);

                hr = pStream->SaveToFile(szFileName, ADODB::adSaveCreateOverWrite);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"save to file failed", L"", 0);

                //cleanup
                pRS->Close();
                pConn->Close();
                pStream->Close();
                CoUninitialize();
                MessageBeep(0);
            }
            catch (_com_error e)
            {
                MessageBox(hDlg, (LPWSTR)e.Description(), L"", 0);
            }
        }
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

7.) Rework `About` dialog box in `rc` editor like below:

[image]

- Spin control has `auto buddy`, `right align, and`set buddy integer` styles set
- buttons are simple push buttons, nothing special
- edit control is simple, nothing special

8.) Create MS Access database with following fields:

- Table name: *test*
- First field: *ID* `autonumber`, `primary key`
- Second field: *field* `OLE Object`
- Third field: *tip* `text`  **this field stores the name of the file ( file.extension)**

*HOW TO USE THIS APP:*

When you run application, open `About` menu item so dialogbox can pop. Choose database we created.

Click the left button ( from the blue circle in the previously submitted image ). Open file dialogbox pops and you can choose any file ( I have tried with `.pdf`, `.exe`, `.zip` and `jpeg` ). File should be inserted into database.

To read BLOB and save it in the same place your app is running, type the number of record you wish to retrieve and press right button ( from the red circle in the previously submitted picture ). BLOB should be loaded and then saved in the same place where your app is.

### FINAL NOTES:

This is not a production code, please be aware of that. This is just the smallest, simplest code example that illustrates the problem.

Again, if you insert BLOB and then try to load it, nothing happens but code runs without error.

If you insert BLOB, **then close dialog box, open dialog box again** and then try to load BLOB from database everything works fine.

### QUESTION:

How can I rewrite my code so I can insert, and then load BLOB without resorting to the "solution #2" described earlier.

**EDIT :**

*I have tried my app on D partition and it works. This means that the problem lies somewhere in the permissions. Can you help me with this because I have no clue how o start solving this?*

**END OF EDIT**

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, when I solve the problem on my own, and there are no answers, I simply delete the question. However, the code posted could be great working example for future generations.

The problem was in my construction of file path. After rewriting my code as below, everything works. Here is the complete dialog procedure:

```
// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    // connection string
    static wchar_t bstrConnect[MAX_PATH];
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        wchar_t szFile[MAX_PATH];
        OpenFile(hDlg, szFile, L".accdb\0");
        swprintf_s(bstrConnect, MAX_PATH, 
            L"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = %s;", szFile);
    }
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDC_BUTTON1:
        {
            wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"";

            if (OpenFile(hDlg, szFileName, L"All files\0*.*"))
            {
                try
                {
                    // disable write button, just in case, until we finish inserting
                    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON3), FALSE);

                    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

                    ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn(L"ADODB.Connection");
                    ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS(L"ADODB.Recordset");

                    hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, L"", L"", 
                        ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);
                    // create new recordset 
                    pRS->Open(L"test", _variant_t((IDispatch*)pConn, true),
                        ADODB::adOpenKeyset, ADODB::adLockOptimistic, 
                        ADODB::adCmdTable);
                    // create stream object
                    ADODB::_StreamPtr pStream(L"ADODB.Stream");
                    // set stream type
                    pStream->Type = ADODB::adTypeBinary;
                    // missing parameter
                    _variant_t varOptional(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);  
                    // open stream
                    pStream->Open(varOptional, ADODB::adModeUnknown,
                        ADODB::adOpenStreamUnspecified, _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""));
                    // open selected file
                    hr = pStream->LoadFromFile(szFileName);
                    if(FAILED(hr))
                        throw _com_error(hr);
                    // add new blank  record
                    pRS->AddNew();
                    // position stream
                    pStream->Position = 0;
                    // insert data to recordset
                    PathStripPath(szFileName);  // leave only filename
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"tip")->Value = szFileName; // store filename
                    pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"field")->Value =
                        pStream->Read(ADODB::adReadAll); // store BLOB
                    // insert data
                    pRS->Update();
                    //cleanup
                    pRS->Close();
                    pConn->Close();
                    pStream->Close();
                    CoUninitialize();
                    // now is safe to read BLOB from database so enable load button
                    EnableWindow(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_BUTTON3), TRUE);
                    // make a sound just so we know we made it! :)
                    MessageBeep(0);
                }
                catch (_com_error e)
                {
                   MessageBox(hDlg, (LPWSTR)e.Description(), L"", 0);
                }
            }
        }
            break;
       case IDC_BUTTON3:
        {
            try
            {
                HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                    throw _com_error(hr);

                ADODB::_ConnectionPtr pConn(L"ADODB.Connection");
                ADODB::_RecordsetPtr pRS(L"ADODB.Recordset");

                hr = pConn->Open(bstrConnect, L"", L"", ADODB::adConnectUnspecified);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"connection error", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }


                // create stream object
                ADODB::_StreamPtr pStream(L"ADODB.Stream");
                // set stream type
                pStream->Type = ADODB::adTypeBinary;
                // missing parameter
                _variant_t varOptional(DISP_E_PARAMNOTFOUND, VT_ERROR);  
                hr = pStream->Open(varOptional, ADODB::adModeUnknown,
                    ADODB::adOpenStreamUnspecified, _bstr_t(L""), _bstr_t(L""));

                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"connection error", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                wchar_t query[200] = L"";
                BOOL ok = true;  // needed for error checking ( GetDlgInt -> see the docs )

                swprintf_s(query, 200, L"select tip, field from test where ID = %d;",
                    (int)GetDlgItemInt(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, &ok, FALSE));

                if (!ok)
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"dlgitemint failed", L"", 0);

                hr = pRS->Open(query, _variant_t((IDispatch *)pConn, true),
                    ADODB::adOpenUnspecified, ADODB::adLockPessimistic,
                    ADODB::adCmdText);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"connection error", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                if (NULL == pRS)
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"NULL pRS!", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                if (pRS->BOF && pRS->AdoNSEOF)
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"empty rs", L"", 0);

                hr = pStream->Write(pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"field")->Value);

                if (!pStream->GetSize())
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"stream write failed", L"", 0);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"stream write failed", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                // save to file
                wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH] = L"";

                // this returns directory where our exe is running
                GetModuleFileName(NULL, szFileName, MAX_PATH);
                // now we remove name and extension of the exe file
                PathRemoveFileSpec(szFileName);
                // add backslash at the end
                PathAddBackslash(szFileName);
                // now we "glue" the name of our BLOB ( we stored it into DB )
                wcscat_s(szFileName, MAX_PATH,
                   pRS->Fields->GetItem(L"tip")->Value.bstrVal);

                if (!wcslen(szFileName))
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"load field name failed", L"", 0);

                hr = pStream->SaveToFile(szFileName, ADODB::adSaveCreateOverWrite);

                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    MessageBox(hDlg, L"save to file failed", L"", 0);
                    throw _com_error(hr);
                }

                //cleanup
                pRS->Close();
                pConn->Close();
                pStream->Close();
                CoUninitialize();
                // beep so we know all went well
                MessageBeep(0);
            }
            catch (_com_error e)
            {
                MessageBox(hDlg, (LPWSTR)e.Description(), L"", 0);
            }
        }
            break;
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }    
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

This was only a test code, but still the important part for me worked ( insert or load + save BLOB ). Hopefully it will be useful to future readers.

In case other members have suggestions for improving the part of code that reads / writes BLOB please leave a comment. Constructive criticism is always welcome.

*I have rewritten code so that almost any fle can be stored. I have tested GIF, PDF, DOCX, XLSX, JPEG, BMP, EXE and TXT, with success. I have also ran my app on USB and it worked well too.*